# Calculate how long does it take to complete a task by two workers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> It takes 36 days for Mr. A to complete a certain task, and 18 days for
>   Mr. B to complete the same task. When Mr. A performs the task together
>   with Mr. B, approximately how many days does it take to complete the
>   task? Here, the task can be divided and performed in parallel, and
>   both Mr. A and Mr. B can achieve an average working efficiency of 90 %
>   every day during the cooperative task

Mr A finishes the task in 36 days, so every day he completes 1/36 the works of the task

Mr B finishes the task in 18 days, so every day he completes 1/18 the works of the task

When the 2 of them working together on a task : 1/36 + 1/18 = 1, which gives me the result of 10.8 days for them to finish the task.

But the right answer is 14 days. Can you point out what am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Every day, the 2 of them complete $(1/36+1/18)\times 0.9=\frac{3}{40}$. The answer is therefore $14$, the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to $\frac{40}{3}$.

Comment: To relax a little bit, a graph shows it: http://imgur.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/pb4bHxH :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of days is $n$ then $\frac{9}{10}n(\frac{1}{18} + \frac{1}{36}) = 1$ by your reasoning. The extra $\frac{9}{10}$ is for their efficiency.

Isolating $n$ then gives $n = \frac{40}{3} = 13.33$ days. So they finish during the 14th day.

Comment: Thanks alot! I made a mistake, I forgot they have to work longer than the result (12 days), not shorter!

Answer (score 1):

If two guys at 100% efficiency would take 12 days to finish the task, as you calculated, then if they work at only 90% efficiency it will take them *longer* than 12 days to finish.  But your answer of 10.8 days says that they can finish the task *faster* by working together.

Comment: AHHHHH!!! What a blunder I made! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\dfrac{\rm together\ time}{\rm A\ time} + \frac{\rm together\ time}{\rm B\ time} = 1.$$

At 90% efficiency it takes $A$ $18/.9 = 20$ days to complete the task and $B$ $36/.9 = 40$ days.

So $$\frac{x}{20} + \frac{x}{40} = 1$$
which gives you $x=40/3 \approx 13.3$.

Comment: Did you read the question? You seem to have ignored the part about “Mr. A and Mr. B can achieve an average working efficiency of 90 % every day during the cooperative task”, and this appears to be the part that OP was having trouble with.